# Is it possible to authenticate a Server by using its public Key in Client?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunneling, gnu

Our existing mechanism, for password less authentication in GNU/Linux, is to create the ssh-keygen in the client and copy the public key of client to server and the server can be authenticated from client without password.

**my question is**,

Rather than create the key pairs in client side, Can we generate key pairs in server (which we want to connect without password from client) by placing the server's public key in client side?

If we can do that what is the procedure for that can anyone explain?

Comment: You seem to have rolled back some fixes to the grammar, of your question. Is there a reason? Also you don't generate an `ssh-keygen` you use it to generate a key (maybe this is also a grammar error).

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

NO.

## Long answer

You can use a bit of publicly known information (a public key), to prove why you are. Furthermore. You can not use the servers key: you are you, it is the server.

Public keys can, safely, be known by the whole world. You server will tell its public key to anyone that asks.

## Longer answer

However if I try to deconstruct what you are trying to do. I see that you are trying to make it easier to administer. So what choices do you have?

- Take all the user public keys and copy them to the server. They can all go in one account, or into many.
- Give all users the same private key. (This may be what you were trying to think of.) This way the server has one public key. However There is no way to tell users apart. There is now way to revoke the key (if a user losses it), without revoking it for all.
- Have the system admin create public and private keys for users. You have to then securely get the private key to the users (e.g. take laptops to IT-support office, and install key). It would also not be safe for the user to use this key for any other purpose (As you should not trust the IT-support, with stuff that does not concern them).

Comment: what i am asking is:-

Comment: think i have two servers A and B i will create Public and Private key in B server and i will copy public key to A server authorised keys and i want to access B from A without password.Is that possible?

Comment: Please put updates in question: And yes but no. You are mixing things up. This will allow you to access A from B.